# Rails 4 - find entity through many to many attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many, join

I have three model objects in my rails app, `User`, `Member`, `Team`, where `Member` is my join table. Some member objects can be admins of a specific team, in my `Member` model I therefore have an admin bool attribute. In some of my views I want to check whether the `current_user` is an admin of any specific team.

My relevant team model looks like this:

```
has_many :members, after_add: :set_admin
has_many :users, through: :members
has_many :admins, -> { where("admin = 1") }, through: :members, source: :user

def set_admin

  self.members.first.admin = true

end
```

I want the user that creates the team to be an admin, therefore my `set_admin` method. Let me know if there is a better way to do it.

In my view I would like to do something like (HAML):

```
- if @team.admins.include?(current_user)
    ...
```

But this doesn't work. I'm not quite sure wether it is because the admin property doesn't get set. Or if there is some other problem, I'm not sure that .include?(current_user) works.

Any idea on what I can do?

**update**

This is how I create users and teams. In my `UsersController` I have:

```
# GET /users/new
def new
  @user = User.new
  @team = @user.teams.build
end
```

In my user model I have:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :teams
```

When user's signs up I also creates teams.

Comment: is that your `Team` or your `User` model ?

Comment: Oh, it's my team model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `Member` define

```
class Member
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team

  def self.admin
    where(:admin => 1)
  end
end
```

Then you can write

```
@team.members.admin
```

which will give you the list of all admin members (not users).

And then, you can add the following method on `Team`

```
def is_admin(user)
  self.members.admin.where(:user_id => user.id).count == 1
end
```

**[UPDATE]** You do set the admin flag, but is never saved. So your method should like

```
def set_admin
  if self.members.admin.count == 0
    self.members.first.update_atributes admin: 1
  end
end
```

I also test if there already is an admin, and only set it if not. otherwise you will set the first member to admin every time a member is added. But it is possible that is what you want.

UI/UX wise i would not like a random member becoming the admin, but rather the team creator immediately has to assign a team admin, upon creation of the team.

**[UPDATE 2]** You define the `set_admin` method on the association `members` of `team`, yet you do not use that relation to build the member, so that method is never triggered. 
You could have easily verified this by adding a log-method.

You create a user, with a new team, so you could add a method on the `teams` association. But this seems a little superfluous to me: you know which team you are adding, and which user.

In your controller you will have something like (just guessing)

```
user.save
```

which will create the user and the nested team, and by definition, the member in between. I would go for the explicit approach.

Option 1: after the save, add this line

```
user.members.last.update_attributes admin: true
```

since the last-added member-relation is the one just created. This feels a little dirty though.

Option 2: after the save, add this line

```
user.teams.last.set_admin
```

This reads a little nicer. So and then you can remove the `after_add: :set_admin` option, since the admin flag is set correctly on creation, and will not be needed when new members are added.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your approach. Should work. But it doesn't seem like my admin attribute ever gets set to true despise this: `has_many :members, after_add: :set_admin`. Any ideas why this happens, or how should I set that property? When a user creates a team I want admin set to yes for that user...

Comment: Ow i overlooked that indeed, i extended my answer.

Comment: Thakns! I've now tried that as well, but it doesn't seem to help. In my views I now use: `- if @team.is_admin(current_user)`, but this never gets set to true. Any more ideas?

Comment: Check the database? Is it set?

Comment: No,  it's nil in the rails console.

Comment: How do you add a member to a team? Or more precisely, how do you make a user a member of a team.

Comment: Ok, that method is never triggered, since you do not build the member using that association. I updated my answer.

Comment: Got it to work, I also had to do one minor change in my is_admin method, so it reruns a bool and not a member.

Comment: The `is_admin` method, as I proposed, already returned a boolean, no? So what did you need to change? Anyway, glad you got it to work.

Comment: I didn't get it working until I added an if statement in `is_admin`,    if the result in a nil, I explicitly return false, othwewise true.

Comment: ???? you are not talking about the `is_admin` I showed here, are you? Nothing could be nil there. But you did not show any other `is_admin` so you got me confused.

Comment: Are you sure, but what happens when `self.members.admins.where(:user_id => user.id).count == 1` doesn't match the given user id?

Comment: It builds a select, for which you do a count, which will return 0 if it does not match, and 1 if it does (because I assume a user as admin will be linked only once). This build a sql query, it is all `ActiveRecord::Relation` so afaik there is no part the could be `nil`.